# datepicker disable date based on time

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker on my website but now I want to disable days based on time. I want to achieve 2 things:

1. I want to disable today, user should not be able to select today's date.
2. Everyday after 2:00pm I want to disable tomorrow also.

Is it possible through jquery?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI datepicker ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about changing minDate according to hour of the day?

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
$("element").datepicker({ minDate: hour >= 14 ? 2 : 1});
```