# datepicker disable date based on time (excluding weekends)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

My question is very similar to question [datepicker disable date based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713125/datepicker-disable-date-based-on-time) this post. The solution given in that post works fine but I have one additional requirement which is I have to exclude weekends, the current solution does not  exclude weekends.

Comment: You need to put all the information in this question. Show us your code, tell us what you have tried, what result you are getting and what result you'd like to get

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11713290/5346109) to the question you mentioned to disable weekends too:

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
$("element").datepicker({
    minDate: hour >= 14 ? 2 : 1,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

Does it help you?